# What's the word for something that you have to do, even though you don't want to

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for something that you have to do (mainly because someone is expecting you to do), even though you don't want to do it, but you still do it. In other words, doing something that you are not interested in doing.

Example: *Jenny hates babysitting her niece, but she has to do it for the sake of her sister and the love she has for her niece.*

Comment: Around here it's called a "honeydo".

Comment: _"I've come too far for anything else. I am Loki, of Asgard and I am **burdened** with glorious purpose."_

Comment: Jenny  is reluctant.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pe6VFuCcBo

Comment: If the obligation is placed upon you by one of the Little People, it's a geas!

Comment: Lot’s of people call it **work**

Comment: obligation, duty

Comment: It is an "Obligation"

Comment: Despite the foregoing, it's really taxes after all. Can I say that? Did I just contradict myself?

Answer (score 61):

Perhaps you are thinking of an "**obligation**."

See the definition at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obligation?s=t) (link direct to word entry).

> 1) something by which a person is bound or obliged to do certain things, and which arises out of a sense of duty or results from custom, law, etc.

Comment: None of those definitions mention disinterest, but merely duty.

Comment: Aha yes, I should've thought of "obligation".

Comment: @RobertHarvey The fact that it arises out of a sense of duty or something similar implies that the actions are taken for that reason, rather than due to intrinsic interest.

Comment: @DCShannon: Yes, but that's a neutral connotation, not a negative one.  The OP specifically mentioned "hate."

Answer (score 38):

Housework that must be done is usually called a **chore**, whether it is done in the house or not.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chore)

> chore noun
>   A job or piece of work that is often boring or unpleasant but needs to be done regularly

Comment: This is what I immediately thought of when I read the question.

Answer (score 24):

I think the words ***[burden](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burden?s=t)*** and ***[onus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/onus?s=t)*** might be what you're looking for. In particular, they both have the sense of a responsibility which is unwanted.

**burden:** that which is borne with difficulty; obligation; onus

**onus:** a difficult or disagreeable obligation, task, burden, etc.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low-quality for its length and content. Can you expand your answer with dictionary definitions explaining why the two words fit in the OP's context?

Comment: I agree with this answer -- while *duty* or *obligation* is a good word for something you have to do ([obligation: "something by which a person is bound or obliged to do certain things, and which arises out of a sense of duty or results from custom, law, etc."](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obligation?s=t)), it makes no statement about the attitude toward the duty, which could as easily be positive as negative.  But *burden* (["that which is borne with difficulty; obligation; onus"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burden?s=t)) clearly communications the negative aspect.

Answer (score 12):

I would call that a **duty**.

Duty doesn't *necessarily* carry the connotation of something you don't want to do, but it isn't usually used to describe something that you're excited about doing, but rather something that you need to do due to an external impetus.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duty):

> **2 a:** obligatory tasks, conduct, service, or functions that arise from one's position (as in life or in a group)
>
> **3 a:**  a moral or legal obligation

Answer (score 7):

Imposition.

> 1. the laying on of something as a burden or obligation.
> 2. something imposed, as a burden or duty.
> 3. the act of imposing by or as if by authority.

Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
Answers which consist of virtually nothing but a dictionary entry (or other external reference) are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. 
Also, do not answer questions which are unclear, out of scope, or already answered many times before. The question is out of scope. Word or phrase requests must be expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 5):

*Jenny hates babysitting her niece, but she has to **go through the motions** the sake of her sister and the love she has for her niece.*

> **go through the motions** — to do something because you are expected to do it and not because you want to (often in continuous tenses) *These days when we go out, cook a meal together or even make love, I get the feeling that he's just going through the motions.*
>   — [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+through+the+motions)

Answer (score 4):

Another common one would be **responsibility**

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/responsibility)

> **responsibility** - noun
>   Something that it is your job or duty to deal with

Answer (score 3):

To do something **begrudgingly** is to give or expend with reluctance or resentment.

You can also **begrudge** a task, that is to be reluctant or resentful about it.

Comment: After doing something begrudgingly, you may harbor a grudge about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Necessary Evil** perhaps?

Something you dislike doing but just has to be done.

For Jenny, babysitting her niece is a necessary evil. She really dislikes doing it but she has to for the sake of her sister and the love she has for her niece.

Answer (score 1):

In one word, "**duty**", as mentioned already in another answer, but there is an expression that perfectly fits your scenario, it is imported from French but used this way (in French) in English:

> **[Noblesse oblige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_oblige)**
>    is a French phrase literally meaning "nobility obliges". It denotes the concept that nobility extends beyond mere entitlements and requires the person who holds such status to fulfill social responsibilities, particularly in leadership roles.

In common practice, and the phrase exists in Spanish as well, it means that you do something out of noble duty (without bitterness) as a result of your elevated status (in your provided example, the status being "loving aunt/sister").

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***forced***.

She isn't really interested in doing it but is ***forced*** to do it for her sister and the love she has for her niece.

However, I think it depends on the situation. As you're talking about babysitting here, you may use a more passive word, unlike ***forced***. I'd prefer ***obliged***
as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

No Catlicks on this site? It's called ***penance***, my friends.

(Please note: It's possible that only Catholics use this word for the purpose described in the question. - we're conditioned that way.)