# Doing something even though you don't want to on an internal level

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, medical

It's when you know you're gonna do something that you shouldn't but you do it anyways, like dropping something even though you had no intention of dropping it but the thought of dropping it crossed your mind and you consciously decided not to drop the thing but you did anyways.

The thought process is pretty much "I know I shouldn't do this but I'm going to even though I don't want to".
Might be a medical term, maybe there isn't even a word for it.

Best use I can think of is:
"The patient has been suffering from ____ for a long time"

I'm seeking the word or definition for the act of doing said thing even though you don't want to and made a conscious decision not to but still do.

It's not a compulsion, but more of a momentary dissonance(?) between your brain and your body about what to do.
Not sure if this will clarify it enough.

Comment: Moral conflict.

Comment: That's referring to rational behind the action not the act of actually doing the thing described.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334958/whats-a-word-for-something-that-you-have-to-do-even-if-you-dont-want-to?rq=1

Comment: Maybe Obsessive Compulsive Disorder.

Comment: You asked for the act in your title and comments but your example sentence doesn't fit.

Comment: OCD doesn't quite fit since it's more of a collection of things, and a lot of the time the compulsions are ways of the patients to try and control their anxieties which doesn't describe what I'm looking  for

Comment: @vickyace you should really start reading the comment below the header instead of just blobbing an answer based only on the header... not really helpful

Comment: @Harish nope, looked at like 10 other threads that had pretty similar titles,  none helped

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not an exact fit, but maybe something related to _impulse control_.

Answer (score 1):

One definition of "**lapse**" works quite well.  Often people use the adjective "mental" (*mental lapse*) to emphasize the state of mind issue.

***lapse***
[Definition of lapse at MeriamWebster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lapse)

> 1
>   a :  a slight error typically due to forgetfulness or inattention
>
> *a lapse in table manners*
>
> *a lapse in security*

In you sentence I would tend to use the "mental lapse"

"The patient has been suffering from _~mental lapses~___ for a long time"

Answer (score -1):

A term for a generic, undiagnosed, uncontrollable mental condition may be a [mania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_manias).

Example:

> The patient has been suffering from some kind of mania for a long time.

If it were diagnosed by a trained professional, a more specific word could be used.